# Can t moulding cover 1/8" difference?

Tags: flooring, tile, laminate

I've just ran laminate flooring throughout the floor, except in the bathroom which is tiled.
There's slight floor height difference and the tile is higher by about 1/8". I have a t moulding that I was going to install to transition between laminate and tile. The t moulding is designed for floors of same height.

Can it overcome the 1/8" height difference? Or should I try to shim up the laminate? I don't want to commit before knowing the answer because the t moulding is those kind where you hammer into a channel.

Comment: My thought is that to keep dirt from getting underneath, and to prevent wobbling, I'd shim the T-moulding, e.g., with self-adhesive vinyl tub "caulk" strips, such as this: https://www.homedepot.com/p/Magic-1-1-4-in-x-5-ft-Tub-and-Floor-Peel-and-Stick-Caulk-Strip-in-White-3015/205188852

Comment: You can try another type of transition molding.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem when I did my floor.  I use my table saw to rip one side of the T-moulding by the needed amount.  Mine is closer to 1/4" difference.  I was concerned it would make the T-moulding brittle, but it is still looking after 7 years.